# How to perform an action based on the selected value of a Spinner in on a Button click?

Tags: android, button, spinner

I want to perform an action based on the `Spinner`s selected value inside of the `Button`s `onClick()` method.

How I get the selected item of a `Spinner`?

My code:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
btnConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);
btnConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Here I want to perform an action based on the selected item of a listener
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(); 
}
```

This returns the position of the selected Spinner item, 0 indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
btnConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = spinner.getSelectedItem.toString();
                if(s.compareIgnoreCase("JUMP")){
                        // code to JUMP action
                } else if (s.compareIgnoreCase("THROW")){
                        // code to THROW action
                }
        }
});
```

Comment: your'e welcome @shihab_returns, and I'm honored if you mark my answer as the correct/accepted answer!

Comment: ya, it's my duty to promote your rank..i m new in Stack overflow..
i just toggle the Right click option,it shows right (green color).after a while it remains same which it was..am i right?